# Composite trait not working: the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `[name]`

Tags: rust

When I make a composite trait (name?) that is made of two other traits, the compiler doesn't seem to detect that the two traits are implemented by that composite trait.

**Here is the code:**

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Seek};
use zip::read::ZipArchive;

trait ReadSeek: Read + Seek {}
impl<T: Read + Seek> ReadSeek for T {}

pub struct ArchiveZip<'a> {
    path: &'a str,
    archive: ZipArchive<&'a (dyn ReadSeek)>,
}
```

**And here is the error:**

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&'a (dyn ReadSeek + 'a): std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src/archive/zipfile.rs:12:14
   |
12 |     archive: ZipArchive<&'a (dyn ReadSeek)>,
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `&'a (dyn ReadSeek + 'a)`
   | 
  ::: /Users/nhooey/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/zip-0.5.11/src/read.rs:50:26
   |
50 | pub struct ZipArchive<R: Read + io::Seek> {
   |                          ---- required by this bound in `ZipArchive`
   |
   = note: `std::io::Read` is implemented for `&'a mut (dyn archive::ReadSeek + 'a)`, but not for `&'a (dyn archive::ReadSeek + 'a)`
```

Why does it not detect that the `ReadSeek` trait doesn't implement both `Read` and `Seek`?

(I omitted the other error message that is also complaining about `Seek` in the same way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you can see: `struct ZipArchive<R: Read + io::Seek>`.
This means that the generic argument (`R`) to `ZipArchive` must implement `Read` and `io::Seek`.

You code has: `ZipArchive<&'a (dyn ReadSeek)>`.
`R` in your code is therefore `&'a (dyn ReadSeek)` which is a reference (`&'_ _`). The fact that the object the reference points to implements `Read` and `Seek` doesn't change which traits the reference itself implements.

So, you can either implement your trait for references (in my experience this usually doesn't go well) or you find a way for `R` to be a type that directly implements the required traits.
Looking at the documentation for references, you can see that `Read` and `Seek` are implemented for [mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#impl-Read). Changing you references to be mutable should therefore solve the problem.

Comment: I chose references because I keep getting the “size not know at compile-time” error. I had also tried using `Box` instead of references and that worked but resulted in a different compiler error that I can’t remember now.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for references, I can actually see that `Read` and `Seek` are implemented for [mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#impl-Read). Maybe using mutable references will solve the problem. If you make it work, please say so and I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: Looking at your error message actually also gives this hint: `note: 'std::io::Read' is implemented for '&'a mut (dyn archive::ReadSeek + 'a)', but not for '&'a (dyn archive::ReadSeek + 'a)'`

Comment: Okay I fixed everything by replacing all `Box` with `&dyn` (or `&mut dyn` where applicable for mutable references for `Read` and `Seek` implemented for `ZipArchive`, as you mentioned above).

And it's almost working, except I'm getting this error: `the trait 'From<&dyn std::error::Error>' is not implemented for 'ArchiveError'`, where I'm using `use thiserror::Error;` and have defined: `#[error("Zip file operation failed: {0}")] \n ArchiveZipError(#[from] &'static dyn std::error::Error),`

Comment: It does look like the original problem has been fixed with your solution, though. Thanks for that.